# How to bootstrap inline 2 inputs in html with label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have this two inputs:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Original Amount</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Original Amount</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Its look like this:
[image]

How i inline them? (with the label on top of each)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap grid like this..

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Original Amount</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Original Amount</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/QA9VLz5QXx)

Answer (score 1):

Just put all your example code inside this div element:

```
<div class="form-inline">
  ...
</div>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline for more info.

Comment: the label in not on top.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the label is left side of the input, i want in on top like my attach image.

Comment: Oh, right. Oki, hope you got what you need.
Just one thing about the answer you checked up up there :
the bootstrap grid system is on a total of 12 rows. If you want a nice centered thing, replace the "col-sm-4" by "col-sm-6" classes.